# config.git: remote hung up unexpectedly caused by IllegalArgumentException: Bad Base64 input character at 3 : 45 (decimal)

Tags: base64, bitbucket, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to get spring cloud config up and running by connecting to my bitbucket.
Its like wading through mud. I have finally managed to connect to bitbucket, one exception after another. Now I am getting the error IllegalArgumentException: Bad Base64 input character at 3 : 45 (decimal).

I created a private and public shh keys with the command

```
ssh-keygen -m pem -t rsa -b 4096 -C cava
```

It was originally

```
ssh-keygen -m pem -t rsa -b 4096 -C myemail@com.co
```

But it would not like the char @

This is my yml file

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @activatedProperties@
  application: 
    name: @artifactId@
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@bitbucket.org:tcavanagh/h-fetcher-cpnfig.git
          default-label: main
          clone-on-start: true
          strictHostKeyChecking: false
          ignore-local-ssh-settings: true
          hostKey: rsh-key-1
          hostKeyAlgorithm: ssh-rsa
          privateKey : |
                         -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                          My Private key
                         -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If ssh-keygen -m pem -t rsa -b 4096 is the only way to create a ssh key and Spring cloud config server, will not allow that key because of an encoding error.
Then uri: git@bitbucket will never work.

Or Iam using windows to generate the key. Does the shh key need to be generated on linux,

Comment: Note: this has nothing to do with Git (or Java-the-language); it's purely a spring-cloud thing and has to do with yaml encoding and base64 encoding and whatever decoding process spring-cloud uses. This all happens long before spring-cloud even attempts to run Git.

Comment: Not having used spring-cloud, my guess here is that there are two different decoders clashing. This stuff gets messy; see, e.g., http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html (also note that `45 decimal` is `-`).

Comment: Thanks, I had  afeeling its some sort of decoder clash. Lucky I went a different direction. But this is such a mine field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I went down a blind ally, with all the host key. Its a nightmare. This is the all that needs to be set.

I only went down the host rabbit hole because I had clone-on-start: true in my yml which was throwing an exception channel request failed.
I only included clone-on-start: true, because it was in the example.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @activatedProperties@
  application: 
    name: @artifactId@
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@bitbucket.org:tcavanagh/h-fetcher-cpnfig.git
          default-label: main
          ignore-local-ssh-settings: true
          privateKey : |
                         -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                          My Private key
                         -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```